# Error : "Uncaught Typeerror: cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null" when appending a new <script> to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below fiddle I am receiving this error : 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Looking at the code it the error seems to be thrown here :

```
_$("pds-answer6343621").innerHTML=y6343621
```

I think this is occuring because the script is executing before the document is parsed but since the function is being called within $(document).ready it should work ?

How can fiddle be modified so that script is loaded when function update() is invoked
http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/121/

Fiddle code :

```
   <body>
    <div id="toupdate">
     <div id="toremove">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/5968383.js"></script>
<noscript>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>​

$(document).ready(function() {
update();
                     });

    function update(){
            $('#toremove').remove();
        alert('removed');
$('#toupdate').append('<div id="toupdate"><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js"></scr'+'ipt></div>');

    }

​
```

Comment: Is that line in the 3rd party script you are loading?

Comment: @Rocket yes, that line is in 3rd party script

Comment: can you explain why you need to update the script?

Comment: @Dr.Molle When a button is clicked a .js file is received which needs to update a previous .js in a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external script makes use of `document.write()`

Therefore you cannot inject the script after the document has been loaded, e.g. on domReady

You may try to use an iframe for the poll to be able to update it.

When you only need to update the poll-results, use $.getScript (without removing #toremove)

Comment: $.getScript will break the 'same origin policy'. thanks for suggestion

Comment: No, it doesn't ! External scripts will not be loaded by using AJAX. They will be loaded by injecting a `<script/>`-node into the document, what is not affected by SOP.

Comment: is $.getScript not a shorthand ajax function as specified at :  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: I do not mean jquery's ajax-method, I mean the native AJAX(XHR, XMLHTTPREQUEST) . Not all calls of $.ajax() make use of native AJAX

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're adding `http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6343621.js` twice. Because of this, there are 2 elements with `id = pds-answer6343621`, so `_$("pds-answer6343621")` returns an array of 2 elements instead of a single object. That's why it it fails,

Why are you adding this file twice?

Comment: no, its an external company .js file and I have no control over how it is built, its built by www.polldaddy.com

Comment: it same result if the external .js files are unique : http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/121/

Comment: should it not matter if the files are unique since its initially removed from the dom : $('#toremove').remove();

Comment: @user470184: ok, my fault. Is it mandatory to reference the file dynamically as you're doing?

Comment: I'm trying to update the <script> of a div subsequent to the page being loaded. jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/121 is the only solution I can see which may achieve this so I think it is mandatory to reference the file dynamically, but if you have another solution I can try then great...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the HTML head. You are including the script there, then adding it again with JavaScript. Try taking it out of the head.

Answer (score 0):

because the `y6343621` is null.

```
if ( y6343621 ==null)
  y6343621="";
```